# RestTemplate, Jackson and proguard

Tags: android, jackson, proguard, obfuscation, resttemplate

I'm trying to get app working after obfuscation. I have two simple classes:

```
public class ApiUrlResponseData
{

    @JsonProperty( "@links" )
    List<Link> links;

    public List<Link> getLinks()
    {
        return links;
    }
}

public class Link 
{
    @JsonProperty( "url" )
    String url;

    @JsonProperty( "name" )
    String name;

    @JsonProperty( "mobile" )
    Boolean mobile;

    public Link()
    {
    }

    public Link( String url, String name, Boolean mobile )
    {
        this.url = url;
        this.name = name;
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getUrl()
    {
        return url;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public Boolean isMobile()
    {
        return mobile;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately after obfuscation and request executing `ApiUrlResponseData.getLinks()` returns `null`.

Here is how I'm trying to prevent obfuscation for data objects:

```
 -keepclasseswithmembernames class com.companyname.android.network.data.** {
       public <fields>;
       protected <fields>;
       <fields>;

       @org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.* <fields>;
       @org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.* <init>(...);
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The options `-keepclasseswithmembernames` is pretty exotic: it keeps the names of classes (and of their fields and methods), if the classes have *all* the specified fields and methods. It is mostly useful for preserving JNI classes and methods.

You could keep the annotated fields and methods:

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.* *;
}
```

Unfortunately, you then have to make sure all involved fields and methods are annotated.

It may be easier to keep all fields and methods of serialized classes like these:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.example.ApiUrlResponseData,
                        com.example.Link {
    *;
}
```

You can use wildcards or also annotations to specify them.

Comment: Eric, I'm getting now `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to android.network.dto.Link`. I need to keep names or annotate classes as well. Checking

Comment: You probably still need to keep generic signatures, by adding `-keepattributes Signature`. Jackson probably retrieves them using reflection.